# Does it matter if I adhere to the export agreement with Mountainhome?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Does the export agreement with Mountainhome affect anything except for telling me which goods can be traded more favourably? E.g, does trading those goods affect my relation with Mountainhome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the value of sold goods matters, you are not in any binding agreement. Selling goods that are in high demand may result in more exported wealth, this, however, is untested.